# Transforming a full $4\times4$ symbolic matrix into a full $3\times3$ matrix and an eigenvalue

Tags: eigenvalues

I have a $4\times4$ matrix

A=\begin{pmatrix}
 0.16 (\cos (\text{kx})+2) & 0.55 \cos \left(\frac{\text{kx}}{2}\right)+(0.\, +0.76 i) \sin \left(\frac{\text{kx}}{2}\right) & 0.55 \cos \left(\frac{\text{kx}}{2}\right) & 0.55\\
 0.55 \cos \left(\frac{\text{kx}}{2}\right)-(0.\, +0.76 i) \sin \left(\frac{\text{kx}}{2}\right) & 0.16 (\cos (\text{kx})+2) & 0.55 & 0.55 \cos \left(\frac{\text{kx}}{2}\right) \\
 0.55 \cos \left(\frac{\text{kx}}{2}\right) & 0.55& 0.16 (\cos (\text{kx})+2) & 0.55 \cos \left(\frac{\text{kx}}{2}\right)+(0.\, +0.76 i) \sin \left(\frac{\text{kx}}{2}\right) \\
 0.55 & 0.55 \cos \left(\frac{\text{kx}}{2}\right) & 0.55 \cos \left(\frac{\text{kx}}{2}\right)-(0.\, +0.76 i) \sin \left(\frac{\text{kx}}{2}\right) & 0.16 (\cos (\text{kx})+2) \\
\end{pmatrix}

```
A={{0.16*(2 + Cos[kx]), 0.55*Cos[kx/2] + (a + 0.76*I)*Sin[kx/2], 
      0.55*Cos[kx/2], 
  0.55 }, {0.55*Cos[kx/2] - (a + 0.76*I)*Sin[kx/2], 
      0.16*(2 + Cos[kx]), 0.55 , 0.55*Cos[kx/2]}, 
    {0.55*Cos[kx/2], 0.55, 0.16*(2 + Cos[kx]), 
      0.55*Cos[kx/2] + (a + 0.76*I)*Sin[kx/2]}, {0.55 , 
  0.55*Cos[kx/2], 
      0.55*Cos[kx/2] - (a + 0.76*I)*Sin[kx/2], 0.16*(2 + Cos[kx])}}
```

where $a$ and $k_x$ are real.

I would like to transform this matrix into a full $3 \times 3$ matrix $F_{3\times 3}(k_x,a)$ and a diagonal term $C(k_x,a)$, where $C$ is one of the eigenvalues of A, as

\begin{equation}
A'=U^{-1}A U=\begin{pmatrix}
F_{3 \times 3} & 0_{3\times 1} \\
0_{1 \times 3} & C
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
where $U$ is the transforming matrix. When $U$ is a matrix with eigenvectors on its coloumns, the above transformation simply diagonalizes the full matrix and $F_{3 \times 3}$ will be diagonal.
This particular $U$ is not what I am seeking, as I would like $F_{3\times3}$ to be a full matrix with non-diagonal elements.
In principle, I can get this form of $A'$ using linear combinations of rows and columns. How can I perform such a transformation on A using eigenvectors of A?

Comment: What do you mean by "rewrite" ?

Comment: I meant transforming matrix A into A'. I have edited my title to clarify this point.

Comment: `ArrayPad[Array[a,{3,3}],{0,1}]+DiagonalMatrix[{0,0,0,b}] // TableForm`

Comment: This is not a transformation.

Comment: First you diagonalize A to A'. Then you leave the forth eigenvector untouched and make a base change among eigenvectors 1..3. This will give you a full F matrix. But as see, this base change is arbitrary, there are infinite many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  A = A /. kx -> k x
```

Then

```
      DiagonalMatrix[
 Eigenvalues[A //. Cos[k x] -> ck /. Cos[k x/2] -> ck2] //. 
    Cos[k x] -> ck /. Cos[k x/2] -> ck2 // FullSimplify]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I do not want to have a diagonal matrix. It is important to me that F_{3\times3} be a full matrix and not a diagonal one.

Comment: A diagonal Matrix is a special case of a full matrix

Comment: Indeed! But that is not what I am looking for.